# ARC restriction - Implicit conversion of 'char' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm playing with the mapkit and setting up some annotations. somewhere in my code I have :-

```
#define ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE 1

unsigned char annoType = ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE

annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annoType ];
```

The last line above throws the error `Implicit conversion of 'char' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC`, which is fair enough, I need to explicitly change the annoType to a NSString.

But the odd thing is; if for line (3) I had the below instead :-

```
annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:**ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE**];
```

It compiles without error?
Question is, what is the type of ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE?

Comment: Please work on your code formatting next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE is an integer. An integer can be implicitly converted to a pointer in C, but if you have enabled warnings the compiler should have warned you about this. I don't know why this isn't a compiler error, probably just an oversight.

You should define ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE as an NSString, e.g.

```
#define ANNOTATION_FIRST_TYPE @"1"
```

Comment: Curiously [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:1]; fails to compile as expected. I always thought the directives preprocessor just makes a replace substitution, it seems to do more in this case.